# Discord.js throwing node:events:505 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I am using Discord.js library to build a Discord bot. I am following the [Official Documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html) and I am facing an error while handling events.

File Structure:
[image: File strcuture]

index.js

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config()

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.login(process.env.token)
```

interactionCreate.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName); console.log("command ", interaction.client)
        if (!command) {
            console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
            return;
        }

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
};
```

The slash command worked successfully when I used the below method in index.js file, instead of creating a new interactionCreate.js file

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    console.log(interaction)
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

But as soon as I moved this function to interactionCreate.js file, The program started throwing the following error [image: Error output]

Any help or advice is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the commands file in index.js because your bot doesn't know about the commands method

From the official document you linked,

add this in index.js

```
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection
    // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
```